# Angular - Only a few variables are being printed, what's the mystery?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have 8 (eight) variables

1. produtoNome
2. unidadeUtilizada
3. unidadeNome
4. codigoSistemaFormatado
5. precoPadrao
6. precoCusto
7. valorCustoMedio
8. valorCustoReferencial

These variables are being printed on app.component.html.

The problem:

The variable **produtoNome, unidadeUtilizada, unidadeNome, codigoSistemaFormatado, precoPadrao, precoCusto** is loaded when the method onChangedProduto is clicked. But loading the page again, just produtoNome, **unidadeUtilizada, unidadeNome, codigoSistemaFormatado** is printado. And I can't solve.

**[app.component.ts]**
https://github.com/andersonpablo/ERP/blob/main/produto/produto-ficha-tecnica/produto-ficha-tecnica.component.ts

**[app.component.html]**
https://github.com/andersonpablo/ERP/blob/main/produto/produto-ficha-tecnica/produto-ficha-tecnica.component.html

**app.component.ts**

````
export class ProdutoFichaTecnicaComponent extends AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

    private _produto: Produto;
    produtosComponentes: ProdutoComponente[] = [];
    produtoConsultaCusto: ProdutoConsultaCusto[] = [];
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    produtos: Produto[] = [];
    buscando = false;
    maskQtde = { prefix: '', precision: 3 };

    @Input()
    set fichaTecnica(produto: Produto) {

        this._produto = produto;
        this.preencherForm(produto);
    }

    @Output()
    salvarDados = new EventEmitter<ProdutoComponente[]>();

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private produtoComponenteService: ProdutoComponenteService,
        private service: ProdutoService
    ) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            produtos: this.fb.array([])
        });
    }


    get isValid(): boolean {

        if (this.formGroup.valid && this.produtosComponentesformArray.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return this.isFormVazio();
    }

    get produtosComponentesformArray(): FormArray {
        return this.formGroup.controls['produtos'] as FormArray;
    }

    removerLinha(index: number) {

        const control = this.produtosComponentesformArray;
        control.removeAt(index);
        this.produtos.splice(index, 1);

        if (control.length === 0) {
            this.adicionarLinha();
        }

    }

    onProdutoChanged(produto: Produto, index: number) {
        if (this.validarProduto(produto, index)) {
            this.produtos[index] = produto;
            this.produtosComponentesformArray.at(index).patchValue({
                produtoNome: produto.nome,
                unidadeUtilizada: produto.unidadePrincipal.unidade.id,
                unidadeNome: produto.unidadePrincipal.unidade.sigla,
                codigoSistemaFormatado: produto.codigoSistemaFormatado,
                precoPadrao: produto.precoPadrao,
                precoCusto: produto.precoCusto,
                valorCustoMedio: produto.valorCustoMedio,
                valorCustoReferencial: produto.valorCustoReferencial,
            });
        }
    }

    onModalConfirm() {
        let componentes: ProdutoComponente[] = null;

        if (!this.isFormVazio()) {
            const control = this.produtosComponentesformArray;
            componentes = control.value;
        }

        if (this._produto.id) {

            super.subs = this.produtoComponenteService.salvar(this._produto.id, componentes).subscribe(r => {
                NotificationService.success('Ficha técnica alterada com sucesso.');
                this.salvarDados.emit(null);
            }, error => {
                const message = error.error ? error.error.message : error.message;
                NotificationService.error(message);
            });

        } else {
            this.salvarDados.emit(componentes);
        }
    }

    private validarProduto(produto: Produto, index: number) {

        if (this._produto.id === produto.id) {
            this.limparLinha(index, 'Não é possível incluir o próprio produto composto como componente');
            return false;
        }

        if (this._produto.classificacao === 'CONSUMO') {
            if (produto.classificacao !== 'CONSUMO') {
                this.limparLinha(index, 'Só é possível adicionar Material de Uso e Consumo para este composto');
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (produto.metodoControle === 'NAO_ESTOCAVEL') {
            this.limparLinha(index, 'Não é possível adicionar produto Não Estocável');
            return false;
        }

        const produtoJaInserido = this.produtos.find(p => p.id === produto.id);
        if (produtoJaInserido) {
            this.limparLinha(index, 'Produto já inserido na ficha técnica.');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private limparLinha(index: number, mensagem: string) {
        NotificationService.error(mensagem);

        const controlArray = this.produtosComponentesformArray;

        if (controlArray.length === 1) {
            this.removerLinha(index);
        } else {
            this.removerLinha(index);
            this.adicionarLinha();
        }
    }

    adicionarLinha(produtoFichaTecnica?: ProdutoComponente) {

        const produtoComponente = produtoFichaTecnica ?? new ProdutoComponente();

        const unidadePrincipal = new UnidadePrincipal();
        unidadePrincipal.unidade = new Unidade();
        unidadePrincipal.unidade.sigla = produtoComponente.unidadeNome;

        const produto: Produto = {
            ...new Produto(),
            id: produtoComponente.produto,
            nome: produtoComponente.produtoNome,
            codigoSistemaFormatado: produtoComponente.codigoSistemaFormatado,
            unidadePrincipal: unidadePrincipal,
            valorCustoMedio: produtoComponente.valorCustoMedio,
            valorCustoReferencial: produtoComponente.valorCustoReferencial,
            precoCusto: produtoComponente.precoCusto,
            precoPadrao: produtoComponente.precoPadrao,
        };

        this.produtos.push(produto);

        const novoGrupo = this.criarProdutoFormGroup(produtoComponente);
        this.produtosComponentesformArray.push(novoGrupo);
    }

    private criarProdutoFormGroup(produtoFichaTecnica: ProdutoComponente): FormGroup {

        return this.fb.group({
            produto: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.produto, Validators.required),
            quantidade: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.quantidade, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.00001)]),
            unidadeUtilizada: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.unidadeUtilizada),
            produtoNome: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.produtoNome),
            codigoSistemaFormatado: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.codigoSistemaFormatado),
            unidadeNome: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.unidadeNome),
            precoCusto: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.precoCusto),
            precoPadrao: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.precoPadrao),
            valorCustoMedio: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.valorCustoMedio),
            valorCustoReferencial: this.fb.control(produtoFichaTecnica.valorCustoReferencial),
        });
    }

    private isFormVazio(): boolean {

        const controlArray = this.produtosComponentesformArray;

        if (controlArray.length === 1) {
            const value = controlArray.at(0).value;

            if (value.produto === null && value.quantidade === null) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private preencherForm(produto: Produto) {

        if (produto.componentes?.length) {

            produto.componentes.forEach(produtoComponente => {
                this.adicionarLinha(produtoComponente);
            });
        } else if (produto.id) {

            this.buscando = true;

            super.subs = this.produtoComponenteService.obterPorProdutoPai(this._produto.id).pipe(
                concatMap(produtosComponentes => {

                    if (produtosComponentes.length) {

                        this.produtosComponentes = produtosComponentes;
                        const produtosIds = produtosComponentes.map(pc => pc.produto);

                        const consultaCustofiltro: ProdutoConsultaCustoFiltro = {
                            ...new ProdutoConsultaCustoFiltro(),
                            data: new Date(),
                            produtos: produtosIds
                        };

                        return this.service.calcularCustoMedio(consultaCustofiltro);
                    }

                    return of([] as ProdutoConsultaCusto[]);
                }),
            ).subscribe(consultaCustos => {

                console.log(this.produtosComponentes);
                console.log(consultaCustos);

                 this.produtosComponentes.forEach(produto => {
                     const custo = consultaCustos.find(p => p.produto === produto.produto);
                     produto.valorCustoMedio = custo.valorCustoMedio;
                     produto.valorCustoReferencial = custo.valorCustoReferencial;
                 });
                if (consultaCustos.length) {
                    this.produtosComponentes.forEach(produtoComponente => {
                        this.adicionarLinha(produtoComponente);
                    });
                } else {
                    this.adicionarLinha();
                }
                this.buscando = false;
            });
        } else {
            this.adicionarLinha();
        }
    }
} ```
````

**app.component.html**

```
<app-vo-modal keyTitle="Ficha técnica" (onFinished)="onModalConfirm()" [primaryButtonDisabled]="!isValid || buscando">

    <app-vo-loading [exibir]="buscando"></app-vo-loading>

    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="formGroup && !buscando">
        <table formArrayName="produtos" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" class="text-center">Item</th>
                    <th width="25%" class="text-center">Produto</th>
                    <th width="12%" class="text-center">Código</th>
                    <th width="5%" class="text-center">Unidade</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="text-center">Quantidade</th>
                    <th width="8%" class="text-center">Custo Médio</th>
                    <th width="8%" class="text-center">Custo Total</th>
                    <th width="8%" class="text-center">Preço Venda</th>
                    <th width="8%" class="text-center">Preço Total</th>
                    <th width="8%" class="text-center">Opção</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr [formGroupName]="i"
                *ngFor="let control of produtosComponentesformArray.controls; let i=index; last as isLast">

                <td>
                    {{i+1}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <app-vo-filtro-produtos (valueSelected)="onProdutoChanged($event, i)" [showLabel]="false"
                        [multiple]="false" formControlName="produto" [itens]="produtos[i]"></app-vo-filtro-produtos>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.codigoSistemaFormatado}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.unidadeNome}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="quantidade" class="form-control minw-110" currencyMask
                        [options]="maskQtde">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.valorCustoMedio | currency: 'R$'}}" class="form-control"
                        readonly>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.precoCusto | currency: 'R$'}}" class="form-control"
                        readonly>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.precoPadrao | currency: 'R$'}}" class="form-control"
                        readonly>
                </td>

                
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="{{control.value.valorCustoReferencial | currency: 'R$'}}" class="form-control"
                        readonly>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="removerLinha(i)" tooltip="Remover"
                        container="body">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </button>

                    <button *ngIf="isLast && control.valid" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        (click)="adicionarLinha()" tooltip="Adicionar" container="body">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</app-vo-modal>
```

Comment: You want your 8 variables to be printed when function`onChangedProduto` is triggered?

Comment: Only valorCustoMedio and ValorCustoReferencial are not being printed by clicking onChangedProduto. It is also a problem.

But the main problem is to load the page, only the  variables precoPadrao and precoCusto are not being printed, and they are coming from the same place.

Comment: When you say printed, you mean to not being display on your html page or in the console? Also, the function`onChangedProduto` doesn't even exist on your code sample

Comment: Corretly name:  onProdutoChanged.

Comment: is printed everything  on the console. And in HTML just what I said.